# AngularJS Getting Data response in console as null but in Postman is not null

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, google-chrome

**Postman and Direct URL Response**

```
            "MenuId": 2010,
            "KitchenId": 2005,
            "Categoryid": 1,
            "CategoryName": "Starters",
            "SubCategoryId": 1,
            "SubCategoryName": "Veg Starters",
            "Name": "Paneer Kabab",
            "Description": "Paneer fried",
            "ImageURL": "noimage.png",
            "Foodtype": 1,
            "NetPrice": 70.00,
            "NetGST": 3.50,
            "NetTotal": 83.50,
            "ListPrice": 84.00,
            "ListGST": 4.20,
            "ListTotal": 99.20,
            "PackingCharge": 11.00,
            "Discount": null,
            "TotalOrders": 0.00,
            "Ratings": null,
            "MenuStatus": 1,
            "VegTypeId": 1,
            "GetButton_no": [
              {
                **"ButtonNo_No": 99.20**
              }
            ],
```

**Browser Console**

```
{ "MenuId": 2010,
            "KitchenId": 2005,
            "Categoryid": 1,
            "CategoryName": "Starters",
            "SubCategoryId": 1,
            "SubCategoryName": "Veg Starters",
            "Name": "Paneer Kabab",
            "Description": "Paneer fried",
            "ImageURL": "noimage.png",
            "Foodtype": 1,
            "NetPrice": 70.00,
            "NetGST": 3.50,
            "NetTotal": 83.50,
            "ListPrice": 84.00,
            "ListGST": 4.20,
            "ListTotal": 99.20,
            "PackingCharge": 11.00,
            "Discount": null,
            "TotalOrders": 0.00,
            "Ratings": null,
            "MenuStatus": 1,
            "VegTypeId": 1,
            "GetButton_no": [
              {
                **"ButtonNo_No": null**
              }
            ],
            }
```

Why is the same API Behaving different behaviour , I am using Entity Framework for that.

```
    public IEnumerable<KitchenMenu_CategoryModel> GetKitchenMenubyKitchennew(int kid,string Username)
    {
        var result = db.tblKitchens.Where(x => x.Id == kid).Select(x => new KitchenMenu_CategoryModel
        {
            KitchenId = x.Id,
            KitchenName = x.KitchenName,
            KitchenType = x.KitchenType,
            Area = x.Area,
            Address1 = x.Address1,
            Address2 = x.Address2,
            //CId = x.CityId,
            Pincode = x.Pincode,
            Email = x.Email,
            Website = x.Website,
            Landline = x.Landline,
            Halal = x.Halal,
            Category = x.Category,
            Branches = x.Branches,
            AvgCost = x.AvgCost,
            Fssai = x.Fssai,
            FssaiPath = x.FssaiPath,
            RegisterStatus = x.RegisterStatus,
            Logo = db.tblKitchenMedias.Where(r => r.KitchenId == x.Id).Select(r => r).FirstOrDefault().Logo,
            Banner = db.tblKitchenMedias.Where(s => s.KitchenId == x.Id).Select(s => s).FirstOrDefault().Banner,
            GetCategory = db.tblGetCategories.Where(y => y.Kitchenid == x.Id).Select(y => new CategoryModel
            {
                CategoryId = y.Categoryid,
                Kitchenid = y.Kitchenid,
                CategoryName = y.tblCategory.CategoryName,
                SubCateogry = db.tblGetSubCategories.Where(z => z.Categoryid == y.Categoryid && z.Kitchenid == y.Kitchenid).Select(z => new SubCategoryModel
                {
                    Categoryid = z.Categoryid,
                    SubCategoryName = z.tblSubCategory.SubCategoryName,
                    Kitchenid = z.Kitchenid,
                    GetMenu = db.tblMenus.Where(a => a.SubCategoryId == z.SubCategoryid && a.KitchenId == z.Kitchenid).Select(a => new MenuModel
                    {
                        MenuId = a.MenuId,
                        Name = a.Name,
                        Description = a.Description,
                        Discount = a.Discount,
                        ImageURL = a.ImageURL,
                        ListGST = a.ListGST,
                        ListPrice = a.ListPrice,
                        ListTotal = a.ListTotal,
                        NetGST = a.NetGST,
                        NetPrice = a.NetPrice,
                        TotalOrders = a.TotalOrders,
                        KitchenId = a.KitchenId,
                        SubCategoryId = a.SubCategoryId,
                        MenuStatus = a.MenuStatus,
                        NetTotal = a.NetTotal,
                        VegTypeId = a.VegTypeId,
                        Categoryid = a.Categoryid,
                        CategoryName = a.tblCategory.CategoryName,
                        SubCategoryName = a.tblSubCategory.SubCategoryName,
                        Ratings = a.Ratings,
                        Foodtype = a.Foodtype,
                        PackingCharge = a.PackingCharge,
                        GetButton_no =db.tblcarts.Where(d => d.Username == Username && d.KitchenId == kid && d.MenuId == a.MenuId).Select(d => new ButtonModel
                        {
                            ButtonNo_No =d.TotalPrice,
                        }
                        ).ToList(),
                        //ButtonNo_No = db.tblcarts.Where(d => d.Username == Username && d.KitchenId == a.KitchenId && d.MenuId == a.MenuId).Select(d => d).FirstOrDefault().Quantity,

                        //Button_No =db.spCountCartButton(Username,a.KitchenId,a.MenuId).Select(d=>d).FirstOrDefault(),

                        GetMenuAttribute = db.tblMenuAttributes.Where(b => b.Menuid == a.MenuId).Select(b => new MenuAttributeModel
                        {
                            MenuAttributeId = b.MenuAttributeId,
                            Menuid = b.Menuid,
                            AttributeType = b.AttributeType,
                            MenuAttribute = b.MenuAttribute,
                            MenuDescription = b.MenuDescription,
                            NetPrice = b.NetPrice,
                            NetGST = b.NetGST,
                            NetTotal = b.NetTotal,
                            ListPrice = b.ListPrice,
                            ListGST = b.ListGST,
                            ListTotal = b.ListTotal,
                            PackingCharge = b.PackingCharge,

                        }
               ).ToList(),




                    }
                       ).ToList(),
                }
                    ).ToList(),
            }
            ).ToList(),




        }
        ).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

--API Controller

[Route("api/GetMenuBykidnew")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMenuBykid(int kid, string Username)
        {
            //var data = new List();

```
        ApiBusiness ApiBus = new ApiBusiness();

        var result = ApiBus.GetKitchenMenubyKitchennew(kid, Username);
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JArray.FromObject(result).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

    }
```

The response is very strange getting different response in browser console and postman

Comment: Give the code so that we can identify the mistake and correct it .

Comment: Here is my code ,Can u please help with the issue .

Comment: Is my JSON parsing method wrong ?

Comment: I dont know the solution bro .